# how to set EntityManagerFactory through constructor by @PersistenceUnit annotation

Tags: spring, jpa, annotations

Does anyone know how to set EntityManagerFactory through constructor by  @PersistenceUnit annotation. I could this through xml configuration. But i dont know the corresponding annotation configuration.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
  <bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
</property>
<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myUnit"></property>
```

```
<bean id="handler" class="com.handler.LocalHTHandler">
<constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory"></constructor-arg>
```

And it is working fine. Can we do it through annotation for my handler bean. I heard about @persistanceunit , but it can not be placed in constructor to achieve it. Is that correct?

Answer (score 6):

As @Dherik said you can do this via constructor. Multi data source example below (tested on SpringBoot 2.0.4):

**SomeRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public class SomeRepository {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public TestService(@Qualifier("someEntityManagerFactory") EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
}
```

**SomeDatabaseConfig.java**

```
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "someEntityManagerFactory")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(JpaProperties.class)
class SomeDatabaseConfig {

    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "some";
    private static final String[] PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = {"package.where.you.store.your.entities"};

    @Bean(name = "someDataSourceProps")
    @ConfigurationProperties("some.datasource")
    DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "someDataSource")
    DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("someDataSourceProps") DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "someEntityManagerFactory")
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            JpaProperties jpaProperties,
            @Qualifier("someDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
            @Qualifier("someJpaVendorAdapter") JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        return createEntityManagerFactory(jpaProperties, dataSource, jpaVendorAdapter, PERSISTENCE_UNIT, PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
    }

    @Bean("someJpaVendorAdapter")
    JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(JpaProperties jpaProperties) {
        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(jpaProperties.isShowSql());
        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean(name = "someTransactionManager")
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("someEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    static LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createEntityManagerFactory(JpaProperties jpaProperties, DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter, String persistenceUnit, String[] packagesToScan) {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
        factoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(getVendorProperties(jpaProperties));
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName(persistenceUnit);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    private static Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties(JpaProperties jpaProperties) {
        return jpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(new HibernateSettings());
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(
        exclude = {
                DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
                HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
                DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class
        }
)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Not possible with Spring using JSR 330 annotations. Currently it's not possible to inject EntityManagers into constructors as `@PersistenceContext` is defined to not be allowed on parameters. See [JPA_SPEC-72](https://web.archive.org/web/20160729014534/https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-72) and [Allow injecting EntityManagers through constructor injection (and at non-@PersistenceContext injection points in general) [SPR-10443]](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/15076).

Comment: Hi Jarek.  I upvoted this answer as it is the most concrete thing I've seen on the constructor issue.  The link is now dead..if you could consider looking for an updated reference, that would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, the [Spring team says](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10443?focusedCommentId=97923&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-97923) that is possible inject `EntityManager` by constructor, as they already use on Spring JPA Repository.

Just:

```
private final EntityManager em;

public YourRepository(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}
```

I tested. Works :). No more field injection.

Comment: Could you please guide me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793617/user-defined-bean-method-entitymanagerfactory-in-commondatabaseconfig-spring ?

Comment: This only works if you have just one persistence context. Otherwise you need to somehow specify which one is required

Comment: @MarianKlühspies I don't think this answer deserve a negative vote because I forgot to add an option with multiple persistent contexts (what is an edge case). Also, I believe that answer already help many people.

Comment: @Dherik I personally haven't seen these annotations in use when there is not the need to specify a certain unit by its name. Is it common to use `@PersistenceUnit` / `@PersistenceContext` over `@Autowired` if you just want to inject the default Entity manager?

Comment: @Dherik how it works? If EntityManager closing after transaction, but we can use that more one time…

Answer (score 1):

If you would not like to use Spring Data in your project for some reason (e.g. you're just making a legacy project a bit better), you can create the following `FactoryBean` to make `EntityManager` injectable via constructor injection:

```
/**
 * Makes the {@link EntityManager} injectable via <i>@Autowired</i>,
 * so it can be injected with constructor injection too.
 * (<i>@PersistenceContext</i> cannot be used for constructor injection.)
 */
public static class EntityManagerInjectionFactory extends AbstractFactoryBean<EntityManager> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return EntityManager.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager createInstance() {
        return entityManager;
    }

}
```

Please note, that because we use the `@PersistenceContext` annotation internally, the returned `EntityManager` will be a proper thread-safe proxy, as it would have been injected directly at the place of usage with field injection.

Answer (score 0):

In our code, we have a base dao object which uses the injected entity manager through PersistenceContext:

```
public abstract class BasicJpaDao<T> implements IBasicDao<T> {

    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION, unitName = "default")
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    // Default constructor for Spring
    public BasicJpaDao() {}

    //Use this constructor to set the entity manager yourself
    public BasicJpaDao(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    ...

}
```

The persistence unit is defined in the Application Context file like so:

```
<!-- JPA -->
<!-- Creates an EntityManagerFactory for use with the Hibernate JPA provider -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceGlobal" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="me.comocomo.nutrino.domain.jpa" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />

    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map merge="true">
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="${hibernate.format_sql}" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- jpaVendorAdapter (works in conjunction with the persistence.xml) -->
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="${jpa.database}" />
    <property name="showSql" value="${jpa.showSql}" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="${jpa.dialect}" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="${jpa.generateDdl}" />
</bean>

<!-- In order to enable EntityManager injection -->
<bean id="persistenceAnnotation"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<!-- Transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceGlobal" />
</bean>
```

Similarly, you can create an EntityManagerFactoryFactory class which gets the EntityManagerFactory using Injection, and in turn passes the factory to your bean:

```
@Component
public class EntityManagerFactoryFactory {

    @Inject
    private EntityManagerFactory factory;
}
```

Comment: injecting entitymanger is fine.But i need to pass entitymanager itself to mybean as constructor arguement.

Comment: You can add a default constructor for Spring to use when injecting the EntityManager, and another one for your usage, like in the edit.
You can then inject the Entity Manager into an EntityManagerFactory class of your own, and pass the Entity Manager to your bean.


If this is not what you're looking for, it would help if you elaborate on why you need to manually set the Entity Manager in your bean.

Comment: in the above comment  i did a mistake : i need to pass not entitymanager but entitymanagerfactory to mybean as constructor arg..

Comment: I added another option - EntityManagerFactoryFactory.
If this is what you needed, please accept.
:)