# User-defined bean method 'entityManagerFactory' in 'CommonDatabaseConfig' Spring Boot Batch XML approach

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am developing `Spring Boot Batch Example`. In this example, I have created `BatchJPA` core module which has `Entities, JPARepository and DB configurations`.

This module adding into another Spring Module as dependency and in this module, I am adding code related specific batch jobs (like custom repository etc). I have total 15 batch jobs and I will be creating separate Spring Boot project with BatchJPA dependency.

Now I am getting below error:

```
10-08-2018 20:13:10.122 [main] WARN  org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.refresh - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CustMstrCustomRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
10-08-2018 20:13:10.124 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.logAutoConfigurationReport - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
10-08-2018 20:13:10.251 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter.report - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
    - User-defined bean method 'entityManagerFactory' in 'CommonDatabaseConfig'


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

**CommonDatabaseConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.XXXXX.ABC.repository", 
                    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", 
                    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
public class CommonDatabaseConfig {
    // This is needed
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("ABC.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ABC.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return dataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.XXXXX.ABC.Entity")
                .persistenceUnit("MyDBDev")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor beanPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

**DataTasklet.java**

```
@Service
@Qualifier("DataTasklet")
@Transactional(value="transactionManager") 
public class DataTasklet implements Tasklet {
    // TODO - Here I am getting null - unable to create @Bean here 
    @Autowired
    private CustMstrCustomRepository custMstrCustomRepository;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

        List<CustomCustomEntity> data = CustMstrCustomRepository.getData();

        chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("data", data);

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

**CustMstrCustomRepository.java**

```
@Configuration
@Service
public class CustMstrCustomRepository {

    private static final String SQL= "MY COMPEX JOIN QUERY HERE - ";

    @PersistenceContext
    @Qualifier(value = "entityManagerFactory")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<CustomCustomEntity> getData()() {
        Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(SQL);
        q.setParameter("isActv", "Y");

        List<Object[]> resultList = q.getResultList();

        List<CustomCustomEntity> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object[] objects : resultList) {
            results.add(CustomCustomEntity.builder()
                    .XX((BigDecimal) objects[0])
                    .YY((BigDecimal) objects[1])
                    .ZZ((Date) objects[2])
                    .AA((Date) objects[3])
                    .BB((String) objects[4]).build());           
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MainApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private DataBatchJobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Bean
    public Tasklet dataTasklet() {
        return new DataTasklet();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EdsMainApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        jobLauncher.executeBillingJob();
    }
}
```

**ABC.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task  http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />
    <bean id="jobRepository"  class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>


    <batch:job id="Q" >
        <batch:step id="step1" next="dataDecision">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" ref="QQContextTasklet" />
        </batch:step>

        <batch:decision id="dataDecision" decider="dataDecider">
            <batch:next on="SUCCESS" to="ADataStep" />
        </batch:decision>

        <batch:step id="ADataStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="dataTasklet" />
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="stepScope" class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope">
        <property name="autoProxy" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="QQContextTasklet" class="com.XXXXXX.batch.tasklet.UpdateBillingContextTasklet" scope="step">
        <property name="billRunMode" value="#{jobParameters['runMode']}" />
        <property name="executionContext" value="#{stepExecution.jobExecution.executionContext}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataTasklet" class="com.XXXXXX.batch.tasklet.dataTasklet" />

    <bean id="dataDecider" class="com.XXXXXX.batch.decider.dataDecider" />

    <bean id="custMstrCustomRepository" class="com.XXXXXX.custom.repository.CustMstrCustomRepository" />
</beans>
```